# Guardar archivo .txt con estilos css con Laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel

estoy intentando guardar de manera local un archivo .txt con algunos estilos principalmente por cuestiones de márgenes ya que requiero imprimir el archivo a una medida especifica.

***Controlador***

```
$filename = 'CorteX_' . Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y_H-i-s') . '.txt';
...  
$data = view('pdf.cutx', compact('company', 'user', 'date', 'totalTickets', 'totalRemissions', 'sumSales'))->render();
Storage::disk('cortes')->put($filename, $data);
...
```

esta es la última manera que intente, `pdf.cutx` es un template html5 y obviamente en el navegador se ve perfectamente como quiero que se vea, pero al guardar el archivo todo es texto plano, tambien utilice `strip_tags`, pero solo me quita las etiquetas. ¿Como seria la manera correcta para que me respete los estilos?

Comment: Un archivo de texto no interpreta código CSS, para ello debe ser un archivo HTML y abrirlo o leerlo con `algo` que lo sepa interpretar (normalmente un navegador).

Comment: Si lo sé, pero no hay forma de primero renderizar y después guardar lo renderizado al archivo de texto??, porque eso es lo que primero estoy intentando de hacer renderizar la vista y posteriormente guardarlo, gracias

Comment: mmm... dices.. `guardar lo renderizado al archivo de texto`.  Un `archivo de texto` no contiene formatos, tan solo texto plano.  Diria que lo que pretendes es crear un archivo pero en formato PDF (eso si puede guardar el HTML ya renderizado y hay lectores de PDF en todas las plataformas supongo), no de texto plano.

Comment: Oh vale, entonces buscare una alternativa porque no pretendo crear un archivo PDF